# "Conduction" or "Conduct"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, nouns

Is it okay to say "conduction of medical camp"(as in carry out/hold an event). I know that the noun of 'conduct' is 'conduct'. However, I have seen the word 'conduction' being used in this context very often. Is it acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

The OED lists this as the sole defintion of *conduction*.

> noun: *conduction*
>
> the process by which heat or electricity is directly transmitted through the material of a substance when there is a difference of temperature or of electrical potential between adjoining regions, without movement of the material.
>
> - the process by which sound waves travel through a medium.
> - the transmission of impulses along nerves.
> - the conveying of fluid through a channel.

Other sites such as [CambridgeDictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conduction?q=Conduction#translations) and [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conduction?s=t) also have only one definition of the word *conduction*. The context of these definitions is purely scientific.

The closest link I could find between the verb *conduct*(as in,  organize or carry out) and it's noun *conduct* was this(again, referring to the OED)

> Conduct(n)  the manner in which an organization or activity is managed or directed.
>
> "the conduct of the elections"
>
> synonyms: management, managing, running.
>
> Conduct(v) organize and carry out.
>
> "in the second trial he conducted his own defence"
>
> synonyms: manage, direct, run.

I'd prefer using "conduct of medical camp" (it still seems a little vague, I don't know why). It would be great if you worded your sentence a little differently and used the verb form, though.

Here's a screenshot from NGram. 
[image: conduct vs conduction]

Answer (score 0):

Neither one works in relation to holding an event.

Unfortunately you didn't give us an example sentence so I'll have to make a stab in the dark.

> The medical camp (as in summer camp) was held in City XX this year.
>
> We set up our medical camp at the outskirts of the city next to the river.